# Don't have permission to access /phppgadmin/ on this server

Tags: database, postgresql, postgresql-9.1

I can access my postgres database in phppgadmin with http://localhost/phppgadmin/

but when i try to open my database in phppgadmin with my ip address http://10.128.0.128/phppgadmin/ it can't work :

```
Forbidden

You don't have permission to access /phppgadmin/ on this server.

Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu) Server at 10.128.0.128 Port 80
```

Is there  anyone can solve my problem? Thanks.

I've editted phppgadmin file into :

```
DirectoryIndex index.php
AllowOverride None

order deny,allow
deny from all
allow from 10.128.0.128/255.0.0.0 ::1/128
allow from all
```

But it still doesn't work....

Answer (score 0):

Did you login as `root` user 
it will normally happen when you are not the root user

Comment: I use 'postgres' as postgres user

Comment: The /etc/apache2/conf.d/phppgadmin.conf configuration file by default keeps anyone but localhost from accessing PhpPgAdmin.

Add a line that makes a new allow rule for your IP, so it looks something like this:

<Location /phppgadmin>
  Order deny,allow
  Deny from all
  Allow from [Your client IP]
</Location>

Answer (score 0):

The `/etc/apache2/conf.d/phppgadmin.conf` configuration file by default keeps anyone but localhost from accessing PhpPgAdmin.

Add a line that makes a new allow rule for your IP, so it looks something like this:

```
<Location /phppgadmin>
  Order deny,allow
  Deny from all
  Allow from [Your client IP]
</Location>
```

Comment: i've editted the phppgadmin file, but it still doesn't work. is there any solution? thanks